# rails3 will_paginate hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Looks like will_paginate dosen't support paginating a hash object.
I have a list of articles which is basically a collection of yaml files that i want to output on a page.

```
def index
  @articles = Dir["#{Rails.root}/blog_articles/*.yml"].inject({}) do |h, file|
    h["#{File.basename(file, '.yml')}"] = YAML::load(File.open(file))
    h
  end
end
```

Can anyone suggest me on how to write the pagination for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def index 
  @articles = Dir["#{Rails.root}/blog_articles/*.yml"].inject({}) do |h, file|   
    h["#{File.basename(file, '.yml')}"] = YAML::load(File.open(file)) 
    h 
  end 

  # paginate the keys of the hash instead of the hash itself
  @article_keys = @articles.keys.paginate
end
```

In your views:

```
<% @article_keys.each do |k| %>
  <%= @articles[k] %>
```