# Is it possible to use will_paginate with GROUP BY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a huge database and I want to reduce the query response time by using will_paginate.

I am trying to group my entries by a column and then use the will_paginate to put results into different pages.

I try to do this

```
@list= Persons.find_by_sql(select).group_by {|t| t.gender}
@detail= @list.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

but it gives me this error:`(undefined method paginate for<Hash:0x3de9930>):`

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

[Additional information]

Someone on the will_paginate forum says this:

> Because you already have to load all the users from the database in
>   order to perform the group_by, my suggestion is simply to forget about
>   pagination and output them as-is.

Does it mean there is no point to use GROUP_BY while using will_paginate?

Comment: [Here's how to paginate a hash object with will_paginate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4280660/1013138), just FYI.

Comment: it looks like the `find_by_sql` method is the cause of your query returning a hash rather than a AR object. Depending on what conditions you are passing in the `select` variable, you might be able to change your code to produce an AR object so you can use the `paginate` method. See the guide on Active Record Querying: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @naliwajek thanks for the link, it is very helperful!

Answer (score 2):

```
@paginated_lists = Persons.find_by_sql(select).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
@details = @paginated_lists.to_a.group_by { |t| t.gender }
```

Try this it should work it worked for me :) use @paginated_lists for paginating.

Comment: Interesting, Just what i was looking for. Thanks!