# Will_paginate with hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, will-paginate

I have controller looks like :

```
## controllers/lhgs_controller.rb
def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
  @totalsolds = Totalsold.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page]).order('date asc').group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }
end
```

And views :

```
## index.hmtl.erb
<div id="totalsolds"><%= render 'totalsolds' %></div>

## views/_totalsolds.html.erb

<% @totalsolds.each do |(date, store, nomor), totalsold| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= nomor %></td>
      <td><%= Store.find(store).name %></td>
      <% totalsold.each do |ts| %>
        <td><%= ts.qty == 0 || ts.qty == nil ? "-" :prod.qty %></td> 
      <% end %>
      <td>Rp<%= number_to_currency(totalsold.sum(&:value), :unit => "") %></td>
     <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_bt_path(:store_id => store, :date => date, :nomor => nomor), :class => "btn btn-primer" %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
...
...

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <% line 65 %>
      <%= page_entries_info @totalsolds %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= will_paginate @totalsolds, :style => 'float:right;margin-top:-5px;height:30px;' %>
   </div>
</div>
```

I got an error :

> ArgumentError in Lhgs#index
>
> Showing C:/Sites/cms/app/views/lhgs/_totalsolds.html.erb where line
>   65 raised:
>
> The @lhgs variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the
>   collection object for will_paginate?

I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12222738/1297435) and [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280693/1297435), but I can't figure out how to use it for my case.

**UPDATE** :

I'm not found anywhere `@lhgs` variable, I tried to change `@totalsolds` to `@lhgs` and now my controller lookslike :

```
## controllers/lhgs_controller.rb
def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
  @lhgs = Totalsold.order('date asc').group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }
  @lhgs = @lhgs.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
end
```

And this an error :

```
NoMethodError in LhgsController#index

undefined method `paginate' for #<Hash:0x4c034a0>
```

Use rails console :

```
irb(main):001:0> @lhgs = Totalsold.order('date asc').group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }
.... look at pastebin ......
irb(main):002:0> @lhgs.class
=> Hash
```

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9F7yvYDd)

Comment: I don't see a reference to `@lhgs` anywhere.  Are you sure you've copied the right files?

Comment: me too, I'm confuse. Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Not surprisingly, `will_paginate/array` is for arrays. You have a hash. What would it even mean to paginate a hash?

Comment: @tyler yes, I will to paginate a hash, but i can't figure out..

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to "paginate a hash".  Just think about it -- what are you paginating based on?  Alphabetical order of the keys?

Comment: @tyler : `@lhgs.class` is a Hash, but can you suggest me on how to write the pagination for hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280693)

On controller :

```
def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
  @lhgs = Totalsold.order('date asc').group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }
  @lhgs_keys = @lhgs.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
end
```

And on view :

```
<% @lhgs_keys.each do |k| %>
<% @lhgs[k].group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }.each |(date, store, nomor), totalsold| %>
.....
....
<% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <% line 65 %>
      <%= page_entries_info @lhgs_keys %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= will_paginate @lhgs_keys, :style => 'float:right;margin-top:-5px;height:30px;' %>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
# controllers/lhgs_controller.rb

def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
  @totalsolds = Totalsold.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page]).order('date asc').group_by{ |s| [s.date, s.store_id, s.nomor] }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

And the index.html can be like this:

```
<% @totalsolds.each do |(date, store, nomor), totalsold| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= nomor %></td>
    <td><%= Store.find(store).name %></td>
    <% totalsold.each do |ts| %>
      <td><%= ts.qty == 0 || ts.qty == nil ? "-" :prod.qty %></td> 
    <% end %>
    <td>Rp<%= number_to_currency(totalsold.sum(&:value), :unit => "") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_bt_path(:store_id => store, :date => date, :nomor => nomor), :class => "btn btn-primer" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

...

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <% line 65 %>
    <%= page_entries_info @totalsolds %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <%= will_paginate @totalsolds, :style => 'float:right;margin-top:-5px;height:30px;' %>
  </div>
</div>
```